# Intel HAXM Android Emulator Black Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hardware-acceleration

I tried to run a previously working configuration of Android Emulator with Google API 21 i86 today, and it failed with the following error

```
emulator: VCPU shutdown request
EAX=e0000011 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
ESI=00020800 EDI=c0a47000 EBP=00c63003 ESP=00844000
EIP=008b68fb EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00001000 00000067 00008900 DPL=0 TSS32-avl
GDT=     0084e2c0 0000001f
IDT=     00000000 00000000
CR0=e0000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=008e0000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000000
```

I have updated HAXM to 6.0.1, which I think is the most recent version and downloaded Marshmallow Google API i86, arm, and Marshmallow non Google API i86 and arm. Only the arm versions run, but they run very slowly. All of the Intel Hardware Accelerated versions do not run at all and simply has a black screen and the errors, which keeps looping and appearing.

My HAXM is allocated to 2.0 gb out of 8 gb on my computer. The computer is a core M.

I have tried both with default ram allocated for emulator as well as 1gb for the emulator. I have also tried turning on and off use host GPU. In addition I've tried reinstalling HAXM after rebooting from both SDK manager and Intel's website. Nothing worked.

This setup worked over the summer but I've not tried since. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have troubles with default Android emulator, you can test [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) solution or [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx). For the second one, you can integrate it to Android Studio interface by adding some shortcuts. (cf. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/you-can-now-acquire-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-on-its-own.aspx). They both are ADB compatible and they relies on a virtualization engine (VirtualBox for Genymotion, Hyper-V for the Visual Studio Emulator).